# An error that seems to be caused by an integer overflow for a specific case

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

I am new to this website. I look around for questions that were similar to mine, but found none so I am asking a new one myself. I hope that I format this correctly.

A part of the program that I am writing sums up some large numbers. Here is the code that I currently have:

```
Ball* tmp = player2->RemoveMaxNode();
if (!tmp->GetChosen())
{
    cout << player2->GetHeapType() << " is chosing " << tmp->GetValue() <<  "-" << tmp->GetSumOfDigits() <<endl;
    cout << "Adding " << tmp->GetValue() << " to ";
    cout << player2->GetScore();
    cout << " which should = " << tmp->GetValue() + player2->GetScore() << endl;
    player2->UpdateScore(tmp->GetValue());
    cout << player2->GetHeapType()<< " score now is: ";
    cout << player2->GetScore();
    cout << endl;
    tmp->SetChosen(true);
    numberOfBalls--;
    j++;
    // cout << endl;
}
```

With my UpdateScore() function being:

```
void Heap::UpdateScore(unsigned long int value)
{
    this->currentScore += value;
}
```

This would give me an output of:

```
AGENT1 is chosing 937504347-42
Adding 937504347 to 0 which should = 937504347
AGENT1 score now is: 937504347
AGENT1 is chosing 709551656-44
Adding 709551656 to 937504347 which should = 1647056003
AGENT1 score now is: 1647056003
AGENT1 is chosing 681463104-33
Adding 681463104 to 1647056003 which should = 2328519107
AGENT1  score now is: 2328519107
AGENT1 is chosing 672306410-29
Adding 672306410 to 2328519107 which should = 3000825517
AGENT1 score now is: 3000825517
AGENT1 is chosing 667082001-30
Adding 667082001 to 3000825517 which should = 3667907518
AGENT1 score now is: 3667907518
AGENT1 is chosing 378250713-36
Adding 378250713 to 3667907518 which should = 4046158231
AGENT1 score now is: 4046158231
AGENT1 is chosing 309421734-33
Adding 309421734 to 4046158231 which should = 60612669
AGENT1 score now is: 60612669
AGENT1 is chosing 206733105-27
Adding 206733105 to 60612669 which should = 267345774
AGENT1 score now is: 267345774
AGENT1 is chosing 151431905-29
Adding 151431905 to 267345774 which should = 418777679
AGENT1 score now is: 418777679
AGENT1 is chosing 13048925-32
Adding 13048925 to 418777679 which should = 431826604
AGENT1 score now is: 431826604
```

**Note**: The integer value after a dash is the sum of digits of the value before the dash. This can be disregarded. I went through and calculated all of these manually and they are all correct until it gets to

```
AGENT1 is chosing 309421734-33
Adding 309421734 to 4046158231 which should = 60612669
AGENT1 score now is: 60612669
```

The resulting number from this addition should be 4,355,579,965, but instead it is 60612669. The difference in these two numbers is 4,294,967,296 which I know to be the maximum size of a 2^32 bit integer. So I changed all of my variables to unsigned long int. The value of `tmp` is unsigned long int and so is the score of `player2`. However, the problem persists and I don't know what I can do. I thought this was an integer overflow error so I hardcoded all of the integer values to be added to each other and I got an overflow error.

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:147:53: warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]
         unsigned long int asdf = 937504347+709551656+681463104+672306410+667082001+378250713+309421734+206733105+151431905+13048925;
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

But this can't be the case for my actual program because I would have received an error telling me that it is an overflow, correct? I don't know what to do here, I've tried everything that I can think of. What is going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a readability suggestion, boolean checks are better read as `if something` rather than `if something is true`. So it would be advisable to change `if (tmp->GetChosen() == false)` into `if (! tmp->GetChosen())`.

Comment: @paxdiablo I'll change that now, thanks.

Comment: Try `unsigned long long` or `uint64_t` (`#include <cstdint>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding a statement like:

```
unsigned long int asdf = 937504347 + 709551656;
```

The *int* values `937504347` and `709551656` are added together creating an `int` result, then that is loaded into the `unsigned long` variable. To avoid overflow at the `int`-add stage, you should be already using the correct type, such as:

```
unsigned long int asdf = 937504347UL + 709551656UL;
```

This you already seem to know since you get the compile-time error as the compilers already knows what values you're trying to add.

However, your contention, that you would see the same result for arbitrary values that the compiler does *not* know about at compile time, is incorrect. It will just add the values and rollover unsigned values. It will probably also rollover signed values but, technically, that's undefined behaviour so don't be surprised if it formats your hard disk :-)

---

In any case, the standard only guarantees that types of a higher rank have greater ***or equal*** range to lesser ranks. An `unsigned long` is only *required* to be 32 bits (more correctly, have a range that can be represented by 32 bits). If you want a guaranteed size, use the `uintX_t` types found in `cstdint`. The `uint64_t` type should expand your range considerably, giving you a guaranteed top value of about eighteen quintillion (`18,446,744,073,709,551,615`).